# Deleting blobs from a sub-folder within a container

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to delete some blobs from blob storage, but I don't initially know which blobs to delete. Basically, I want to list the blobs and figure out the most recent one and delete that one. My code looks something like this:

```
private void deleteLatestBlob(String sasUrl, String container)
{
    BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(sasUrl).buildClient();
    BlobContainerClient container = serviceClient.getBlobContainerClient(container);
    List<BlobClient> clients = container.listBlobsByHierarchy("foo/bar/")
        .stream()
        .map(item -> container.getBlobClient(item.getName()))
        .sorted((client1, client2) ->
            client2.getProperties().getLastModified()
                .compareTo(client1.getProperties().getLastModified()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (!clients.isEmpty())
    {
        clients.get(clients.size() - 1).delete(); // Exception happens here
    }
}
```

The goal here is to delete the most recent blob inside of `foo/bar/`. However, I get an exception with message "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.". To avoid spam, a snippet from the stack trace:

```
com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 400, "?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidUri</Code><Message>The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
RequestId:300025de-001e-006e-7644-bfb34b000000
Time:2023-07-25T22:09:35.6134376Z</Message></Error>"
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:370)
        at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$7(RestProxy.java:425)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
... snip...
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1706)
                at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.blockWithOptionalTimeout(StorageImplUtils.java:128)
                at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.deleteWithResponse(BlobClientBase.java:973)
                at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.delete(BlobClientBase.java:944)
```

Given that I'm using the blob name directly from the `BlobItem` I just got from listing, how could the resource be missing?

Comment: From the typos in your post (`serviceCLient` vs `blobServiceClient` for example) it's clear you retyped the code.  DON'T DO THAT -- copy/paste from the real source code.  We can't trust that what we see is what you are actually running, so all bets are off.

Comment: List<BlobClient> but you said it contained the blob names. If you put cookies in a cookie jar you have cookies. But if you put them in a meat grinder, you don't have cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you list blobs using [`listBlobsByHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-java#use-a-hierarchical-listing), it will return both blobs and virtual folders. My guess is that the first item in your list is a virtual folder and since it is not an actual blob, the delete operation is failing with `404 (NotFound)` error.

You can either filter your list by checking if the blob returned is an actual blob by checking [`isPrefix()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.models.blobitem?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-models-blobitem-isprefix()) or you can simply return the list of blobs (and no virtual folders) by using [`flat listing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-java#use-a-flat-listing).

Comment: This was the tip I needed. The folder I was listing contained more folders, and each one of those had a file in it. I wanted to delete the folders, but couldn't do so until I deleted the underlying file inside. So, I listed the files inside first (using a flat listing), deleted those, and then I could delete the folders that had contained them.